# what is the meaning of border_mode in keras?

Tags: theano, keras

I'm confused what to use, valid,same or full. I also don't know what does it do. I can't find it in the Docs. And `border_mode` for `MaxPooling2D` layer does not make sense to me. (It does make sense to me for the Convolution layers though).

Answer (score 7):

When you use a two-dimentional image with `m rows and n cols`, and a `a*b size kernel` to convolute the input image, this is what happens:

If border_mode is *'full'*, returns a `(m+a-1)x(n+b-1)` image;
  if border_mode is *'same'*, returns the same dimention as the input image;
if border_mode is *'valid'*,returns a `(m-a+1)x(n-b+1)` image.
    for example,

**Input**:
In following 4x4 image

`A = [12 13 14 15;1 2 3 4;16 17 18 19;5 6 7 8], and a 3x3 kernel B = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]`,

if border_mode is 'full', then returns a `6x6` matrix;
if border_mode is 'same', then returns a `4x4` matrix;
if border_mode is 'valid', then returns a `2x2` matrix.

you can also use function conv2(A,B,border_mode) in MATLAB to test the output matrix.

Hope this answer could help.

Comment: what is a 'kernal'? I've never seen that word before.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck OP misspelled, the word is [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)).

Answer (score 3):

This is for Keras 2+ as they replaced the Border_mode with padding
And it can be used for down and upsampling in a network.

Answer (score 0):

Border_mode full, same, and valid are explained very well above.

Yes you are right `MaxPooling` is used to reduce the channels if you use `border_mode = full` or `border_mode = same` it doesn't make any sense.